# How to use unallocated place to drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to use the unallocated space of my hard drive, I want to create a new drive or filesystem of that place and want to use. How can i do that.

When i tried to create another partition, it gives me the message that "Can not create partition, there are already 4 primary partitions".

Below is what i can see in GParted :

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 /home size used unused flag
/dev/sda2 extended   size used unused flag
/dev/sda5 ext4 /opt size used unused flag
/dev/sda3 ext4 / size used unused flag
/dev/sda3 linux-swap  size used unused flag
unllocated  435GiB
```

How can i use my unallocated space to /opt or /media

[image]

Comment: you have sda3 listed twice. you have 4 partitions already. so only option: merge it with one of the other partitions.

Comment: there is only one dev/sd3. I am new to ubuntu. So can you please tell me the steps if i want to merge. Actually i am looking to increase the space of /opt but not able to do so.

Comment: Boot from live dvd; rightclick sda5 and see if you can enlarge it. Otherwise format the unallocated to ext4 and then merge sda5 with (I assume) sda6

Answer (score 1):

You can not create more than 4 primary partitions.

You need to remove one of the existing partitions and create one extended partition. Then you will be able to create many logical partitions inside it.

In your case the easiest way will be to re-install Ubuntu. Your partitioning is wrong and it will take lots of effort get it right.

1. There is absolutely no need to have a separate `/opt` partition.
2. You have already 4 primary partitions and the extended partition is in a very awkward place aside to `/` to move everything.
3. Moving the `/` partition will require to re-install grub.

That is not impossible to move sda3 and sda4 to the right, then extend ext2, and then create some new partitions inside sda2.

But I do not see a reason to have this type of partitioning.

That is why I recommend to re-install. You can create one extended partition and inside it `/`, `/home` and `/swap`. And you can live space for installing Windows or other OS`s on 3 other primary partitions, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Gparted. Can you please tell me the procedure. i have updated my question

Comment: It will be better if you post a link to a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: Hi here is the link http://s23.postimg.org/kyp5bzxtn/memory.png

Comment: I agree with the /opt/ not needing a separate partition but there is an exception: if you have loads of 3rd party software. For instance Jasperserver wants to install in /opt with tomcat and some other server software. And all the templates are stored in /opt. Though the 900Gb is far too small to explain a 40Gb /opt in this case.